# Idiomatic way to check if some (not all) properties of two objects equal in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, equality

Let's assume i have a class with two instances:

```
class Car(val id: Int, val color: Color, val pistons: Int, val spoiler: Boolean)

val audi = Car(1234, Color.BLUE, 8, false)
val bmw = Car(4321, Color.WHITE, 6, false)
```

Now i'd like to check equality for some properties (not all -> i'd use a data class in that case)

```
fun looksSimilar(a: Car, b: Car) = a.color == b.color && a.spoiler == b.spoiler
```

I'm now looking for a method which does comparison:

- for more generic objects `T` and their properties
- more idiomatic: no-one wants to read tons of equals-checks
- similarly fast

---

I've come up with the following proposal:

```
fun <T> Pair<T, T>.equalIn(vararg arguments: (T) -> Any?) =
    arguments.toList().all { it(first) == it(second) }
```

which allows me to write the above check as

```
val looksSimilar = (audi to bmw).equalIn({it.color}, {it.spoiler})
```

Does anyone know a better (e.g. cleaner/faster) solution?

---

My usecase is the following:

I'm writing an Android App with multiple `RecyclerView's` (= fancy view to display lists)

Each `RecyclerView` has a `ListAdapter` (responsible for the underlying list)

Each `ListAdapter` requires a `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` (for comparing old & new Items & initiating appropiate changes in the view)

```
val callback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Car>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Car, newItem: Car): Boolean
    // usually checks for id, e.g. oldItem.id == newItem.id

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Car, newItem: Car): Boolean
    // checks if two items look the same.
    // Used for fancy enter/exit animations afaik.
    // e.g. (oldItem to newItem).equalIn({it.color}, {it.spoiler})
}
```

Comment: Tbh, I would heavily prefer simple stupid equality checks over anything more fancy because everyone knows how they look and work. It took my almost 2 minutes to fully understand what your function does and how it works. If there were only simple equality checks instead I would understand them in one second when reading the code.

Comment: At the usage site it would be cleaner to write `.equalIn(Car::color, Car::spoiler)`. Otherwise, your way seems fine to me. Maybe it's a little awkward to require the intermediate Pair. Other than that, this is creating functional objects and arrays to do the check, so there's a bit of GC churn that you wouldn't have by using `==` comparisons directly.

Comment: You don't need any of this if instead of using just `class` you use `data class` that is exactly the reason why `data class` exist, it allows structural comparison by just saying `a == b`, your `Pistons` would also have to be a data class. And usually in the diff item callback the `areItemsTheSame` is the ids comparison and then on the content you use `oldItem == newItem`

Comment: @vatbub i agree that, in the moment, it's not perfect to read; but that's part of my question

Comment: @Tenfour04 I didn't know i could do this, thanks +1

Comment: @cutiko to be honest, i'm not too familiar with the ItemCallback. The documentation of `areContentsTheSame` states "For example, if you are using DiffUtil with a RecyclerView.Adapter, you should return whether the items' visual representations are the same.". For me, this does not necessarily include the ammount of pistons in my example

Comment: Personally instead of the extension function I'd probably make some kind of comparison class (like a ``Comparator`` that only handles ``equals``) so you can create an instance of it, configured how you like, and just use that for all your checks. You could pass in your property list during construction, to define all the checks it should do, and then you create it once - and you can have different variations if you need them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While browsing by StackOverflow history, I found this question again and it tickled my brain, so I thought about it a little. I still stand by my opinion that I prefer explicit if checks (easier to understand IMO, fastest performance), but if  I had to do it with an extension function, I would rather use a list instead of a pair (allowing for more than two inputs) and I would use reference syntax for the lambdas at the call site, making it a little more concise:

```
fun <T> List<T>.equalIn(vararg arguments: (T) -> Any?): Boolean {
    if (isEmpty()) return false
    val argumentsList = arguments.toList()
    return all { item -> argumentsList.all { it(item) == it(first()) } }
}

fun main() {
    val audi = Car(1234, Color.BLUE, 8, false)
    val bmw = Car(4321, Color.BLUE, 6, false)
    println(listOf(audi, bmw).equalIn(Car::color, Car::spoiler))
}
```

Comment: Nice to see a year old question still tickle your brain :D

Comment: I would use `if (isEmpty()) return true` though.